# Why does my program stop when I call a function?

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I'm coding a function which should reverse a given word or input, but the program keep stopping when I call that.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

void reverse(char normal[], char reversed[]);

main() {

    int c, i;
    char line[MAX], reversed_line[MAX];

    for (i=0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        line[i] = c;
        if (c == '\n')
            i++;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    copy(line, reversed_line);
    printf("%s", reversed_line);

    return 0;
}


void reverse(char normal[], char reversed[]) {

    int i, len;

    for (i = 0; normal[i] != '\0'; i++)
        len++;
        
    i = 0;
    while ((reversed[len-i] = normal[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

The line where the program stops is `copy(line, reversed_line);` and the error it gives is `[Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).... to be invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). If allowed, use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Comment: Your first `for` loop in `main` may trigger a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). I recommend using instead [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)... Your error happens at compile time, so read also the documentation of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) which is used by `gcc`. Also `MAX` should be renamed (e.g. as `MAXLINELENGTH`) for readability

Comment: Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and download, then study for inspiration the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). Take inspiration from the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: You should look up any C text book to see how `main` function signature is supposed to look. Implicite `int` type and empty parameter list are features from a century that is long gone.

Comment: Your programming is not "stopping"; it is not running.  You cannot run it until it successfully compiles and links, and in this case it is not linking.  The `copy()` is undefined.  That information is no doubt provided in the diagnostic information you have omitted.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : studying libc or bash source to solve this simple beginner misunderstanding is a sledgehammer to crack a nut and likely to further confuse.  Not a recommendation I'd make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you do not execute your program only try to compile and link it.

The error message indicates that the linking has failed as linker has not found the function `copy`, which indeed is never defined in your code. There is no 'copy' function in the standard library. If you wanted to copy the string or some memory aream you should use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `memcpy` or `memmove`.

But even if the program links you have plenty problems in your code.

Here is working version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5

char *reverse(char *normal, char *reversed);

int main(void) {

    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    char line[MAX], reversed_line[MAX];

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        line[i] = c;
        if(c != '\n') i++;
        if(i >= MAX - 1) break;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';

    reverse(line, reversed_line);
    printf("%s", reversed_line);

    return 0;
}

char *reverse(char *normal, char *reversed) 
{
    size_t size = 0;

    if(normal && reversed)
    {
        while(normal[size]) size++;
        reversed[size] = 0;
        while(size)
        {
            reversed[size - 1] = *normal++;
            size--;
        }
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jb7b6hjfT

Comment: Actually [strncpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) might be preferable to `strcpy`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch same bad or maybe even worse. `strncpy` is a programmer trap.

Comment: Not if the `strncpy` is used with `sizeof(buf)-1` and preceded by `memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf))`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Then it is an extremely inefficient function. It should be done this way: https://godbolt.org/z/oa9obM4oY

Answer (score 2):

For starters in this for loop

```
for (i=0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
    line[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        i++;
}
```

you are not checking whether `i` is greater or equal to `MAX`. And moreover this if statement

```
    if (c == '\n')
        i++;
```

is never executed due to the condition of the loop.

You declared the function `reverse`

```
void reverse(char normal[], char reversed[]);
```

but instead of the function you are trying to call another function `copy`.

```
copy(line, reversed_line);
```

Also this loop within the function `reverse`

```
while ((reversed[len-i] = normal[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
```

is trying to write the terminating zero character `'\0'` in the first position of the character array pointed to by the parameter `reversed`.

What you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

char * reverse_copy( const char normal[], char reversed[] );

int main(void) 
{
    char line[MAX], reversed_line[MAX];

    size_t i = 0;
    
    for  ( int c; i + 1 < MAX && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++ ) 
    {
        line[i] = c;
    }
    
    line[i] = '\0';
    
    puts( reverse_copy( line, reversed_line ) );
    
    return 0;
}

char * reverse_copy( const char normal[], char reversed[] ) 
{
    size_t len = 0;

    while ( normal[len]  != '\0' ) ++len;

    reversed += len;
    
    *reversed = '\0';
    
    for ( ; len != 0; --len )
    {
        *--reversed = *normal++;
    }

    return reversed;
}
```

If to enter for example string

```
Hello World!
```

then the program output will be

```
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: One question, why not use `fgets` to read the input string?

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang As for fgets then I tried to preserve the approach used by the author of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some unnecessary things in your code. For example why do you have this condition in your while-loop in `reverse` when you already know the length?

```
while ((reversed[len - i] = normal[i]) != '\0')
```

I have rewritten your entire code to optimize some things. Maybe it's a helpful addition to [0___________'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951546/14947044). I have included a lot of explaining comments in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000

void reverse(char *str, char *rev_str, size_t len)
{
    /* check if `str` is a valid string */
    if (str == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid string\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* take null character into account */
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i)
            rev_str[len - i - 2] = str[i];
    rev_str[len - 1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX];
    fputs("Input: ", stdout);
    /* just use `fgets` and prevent buffer overflow */
    fgets(str, MAX, stdin);

    /* `len` includes null character */
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    /* change '\n' to '\0' */
    str[len - 1] = '\0';

    /* `sizeof(rev_str)` doesn't always need to be `MAX` */
    char rev_str[len];
    reverse(str, rev_str, len);
    printf("Output: %s\n", rev_str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```